# why I can't set nothing to variable in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I have a a problem with my vb.net.

my code

```
class business{
    buiding as string
}
```

I load data from mongodb

```
Dim collection1 = db1.GetCollection(Of business)("tablebusiness")
Dim list = collection1.Find(query1)
For Each abiz In list
     Dim biztemp = abiz
     biztemp.buiding = nothing '//// (but I get biztemp.building = "") why??
     'biztemp.building = "" here
Next
```

Comment: maybe it should just start with capital letter (Nothing, not nothing). VS corrects it to capital...

Comment: Where do you _get_ `biztemp.building = ""`? Why are you showing pseudo code for the class `business`? That won't compile anyway.

Comment: Maybe you should use the correct types. That will treat the vars as Objects and maybe that is your problem. Try `Dim biztemp As business = abiz` and `For Each abiz As business` etc

Comment: Hmm.... so biztemp may not be of Business type. Let me check on that.